# Reinstalling Windows 7 with Bootcamp on a Mac

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp

I have already installed Windows 7 on my Mac per the installation instructions but didn't use Bootcamp because it didn't specify to do so. I am now wondering if I made a mistake.

Do I need to uninstall Windows 7 and reload using Bootcamp? If so, how do I go about it and get Windows 7 installed correctly?

Comment: So how did install Windows *without* Boot Camp? Are you able to boot both Mac OS X and Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used Bootcamp, but I have used other boot loaders before. If you can boot into your Mac OS still, then you should be able to configure BootCamp to present you with the options.

I am not familiar with how this is done, but knowing Apple, I am sure it is in their options to detect an existing Windows installation. You should not need to "Uninstall" Windows, you should be able to just adjust configurations for BootCamp to deal with your current Windows installation.

Comment: I wouldn't answer a question if I wasn't entirely sure or didn't have any experience with the situation …

Comment: @slhck just because I have limited experience specifically with bootcamp doesn't mean I don't understand boot loaders. I have worked with grub, lilo and BCD's repeatedly over years, so yes I actually do have experience with the situation, thanks.

Comment: *> […] you should be able to configure BootCamp to present you with the options* – what options, actually?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Windows is correctly installed. You are not forced to use the Boot Camp Assistant (available under OS X) to install it -- in fact, with some configurations (for example, if you have multiple partitions) Boot Camp Assistant refuse to "assist" you but you can install Windows by partitioning the disk with Disk Utility and booting manually from the Windows CD at Mac startup;
2. the only thing you need to do now is to install the Bootcamp drivers, so all your hardware is properly recognized. Just start Boot Camp Assistant and at the second step select "Download the latest Windows support software from Apple"; the drivers will be downloaded and will be saved on a USB key or CD. You can then boot into Windows and follow the procedure to install them.

For further information be sure to check out http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/ or print the installation guide at the first step of Boot Camp Assistant.